# Mockito: Verify generic list as argument

Tags: java, mockito, verify

I am stuck trying to verify an argument of a listener implementation.

The method from the `Listener` interface:

```
public void settingsAdded(List<EditJobSettings> addedSettings);
```

What I want to do is check if the expected objects are present in the list.

The test (left out irrelevant code):

```
@Test
public void initiallyAddColorAndAlignTile() {

    mSettings.add(mColorSetting);

    // This method calls the listener method and passes the added settings as argument
    mStatusNotifier.notifySettingsUpdates(mSettings);

    // Here I get stuck: this does not compile, but I can't find how to work around this. Is there a way to specify a generic list as argument?
    ArgumentCaptor<List<EditJobSettingsSet>> argument = (List<EditJobSettingsSet>) ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);

    verify(mEditJobListener).settingsAdded(argument.capture());

    assertTrue(argument.getValue().contains(mColorSettings));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cast is failing because you're casting an `ArgumentCaptor<stuff>` to a `List<stuff>`.

If you are already calling `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`, you can just declare a field as a [`@Captor`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Captor.html), which is the easiest way to reduce the repetition:

```
public class YourTest {

  @Mock SomeClass someMock;
  @Captor ArgumentCaptor<List<EditJobSettingsSet>> argument;

  @Before public void initializeMocks() {
    // This gets called automatically if you @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class).
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test public void yourTest() {
    // [insert setup here]
    verify(mEditJobListener).settingsAdded(argument.capture());
    // [insert assertions here]
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you're going to have to cast something *approximating* this (which I will test when I can):

```
// Might not work without the cast to (ArgumentCaptor) and some @SuppressWarnings.
ArgumentCaptor<List<EditJobSettingsSet>> argument = 
    (ArgumentCaptor<List<EditJobSettingsSet>>)
    ((ArgumentCaptor) ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class));
```

Comment: I've not tested it with the annotation, but I've tested the code at the end, and it doesn't compile.

Comment: @JBNizet I know the annotation works, and is the preferred way to handle complex generics in Captors. I don't remember offhand how forgiving the unsafe casts are, or how much can be muted away with a cast to `(ArgumentCaptor)` and/or use of `@SuppressWarnings`. Will test when I have an IDE handy; updating answer in the meantime.

Comment: sorry for the late response, figured it out eventually. the @Captor is pretty cool, didn't know that yet. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
ArgumentCaptor<List<EditJobSettingsSet>> argument = 
    (List<EditJobSettingsSet>) ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);
```

You're trying to initialize a variable of type `ArgumentCaptor<List<EditJobSettingsSet>>` with a `List<EditJobSettingsSet>`, and to cast the result of `ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class)` (which is of type ArgumentCaptor) to a List. That doesn't make sense. What you want is

```
ArgumentCaptor<List> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);
verify(mEditJobListener).settingsAdded((List<EditJobSettingsSet>) argument.capture());
List<EditJobSettingsSet> value = argument.getValue();
assertTrue(value.contains(mColorSettings));
```

I'm not sure there is a way to avoid using a `ArgumentCaptor<List<EditJobSettingsSet>>` here.

Comment: +1, the other answer is what I have in my code now, you were right about the silly cast indeed... :). Thanks for the answer!